# How to create a function which randomly jumbles a string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

My main function contains a string that I would like to jumble. I have found a piece of code which passes in a `char*` and returns 0 when complete. I have followed the code providers instructions to simply pass in the string which you would like to have jumbled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int scrambleString(char* str)
{
     int x = strlen(str);
     srand(time(NULL));
     for(int y = x; y >=0; y--)
     {
          swap(str[rand()%x],str[y-1]);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

When I do this, I recieve an error that `"no suitable conversion function "std::string" to "char*" exists`.

I have also tried passing in a `const char*` but that won't allow me to access the word and change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you mixing `std::string` with `char*`?  You should just operate directly on the string:

```
void scrambleString(std::string& str) 
{
    int x = str.length();
    for(int y = x; y > 0; y--) 
    { 
        int pos = rand()%x;
        char tmp = str[y-1];
        str[y-1] = str[pos];
        str[pos] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Usage becomes:

```
    std::string value = "This is a test";
    scrambleString(value);
```

That being said, [std::random_shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) will do this for you...

Answer (score 7):

Try this instead:

```
std::string s = "Hello";
std::random_shuffle(s.begin(),s.end());
```

By the way, don't forget to include `<algorithm>` in order to use `std::random_shuffle`, and you need to include `<string>` for `std::string`. `<string.h>` is for the c-string library, and if you're going to use that in C++, you should actually use `<cstring>` instead.

Comment: everything I wanted to say with the addition of instead of `using namespace std;` consider `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

std::string class cannot be converted to char* implicitly.
You have to use string.c_str() to convert to const char* from std::string.

Notice c_str() returns a const pointer to the string copied from std::string internal storage so you cannot change its content. instead, you have to copy to another array or vector.

Comment: if you are going to use C++ and STL ... why have char* at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this:

std::string stringToScramble = "hello world";

scramble(stringToScramble.c_str());

Notice the use of .c_str() which should convert the string into the format that you need.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write random char data into a string, the C++ way using [random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) library is:

```
#include <random>

std::string mystring = "scramble this please";

std::default_random_engine rng;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rng_dist(0, 255);
for(unsigned int n = 0; n != mystring.size(); ++n) {
  mystring[n] = static_cast<unsigned char>(rng_dist(rng));
}
```

Comment: -1, as the (old, answered) question wasn't about filling a string with random characters, but rather with shuffling the order of the characters in a string randomly.