# Better way to shuffle elements of a string in R

Tags: r, string, shuffle

I have to shuffle elements of a string. I wrote a code:

```
sequ <- "GCTTCG"
set.seed(2017)
i <- sample(1:nchar(sequ))
separate.seq.letters <- unlist(strsplit(sequ, ""))
paste(separate.seq.letters[i], collapse = "")
[1] "GTCGTC"
```

This code shuffles elements one time. The main question would be is there a better (more effective) way to do that? For very long sequences and huge amount of shuffles `strsplit`, `paste` commands takes some extra time.

Comment: Create  a function with this and use `replicate` i.e. `f1 <- function(str1){
        s1 <- unlist(strsplit(str1, ""));
        paste(s1[sample(nchar(str1))], collapse="");
    }; replicate(10, f1(sequ))`

Comment: Because you have a benchmark-centric question, please provide an example of sufficient size, current timings and expected timings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making use of the [Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org/) package to handle in C is probably fastest.

Below I've done some benchmarking of a handful of approaches suggested so far, including:

- Approach in the QUESTION
- Approach in COMMENT by @akrun
- Approach using BIOSTRINGS package, suggested by @knb
- Approach using the STRINGI package, suggested by @Rich
- A custom RCPP function, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037073/how-to-create-a-function-which-randomly-jumbles-a-string).

Except for the stringi function, here are the others wrapped into functions for testing:

```
f_question <- function(s) {
  i <- sample(1:nchar(s))
  separate.seq.letters <- unlist(strsplit(s, ""))
  paste(separate.seq.letters[i], collapse = "")
}

f_comment <- function(s) {
  s1 <- unlist(strsplit(s, ""))
  paste(s1[sample(nchar(s))], collapse="")
}

library(Biostrings)
f_biostring <- function(s) {
  probes <- DNAStringSet(s)
  lapply(probes, sample)
}

Rcpp::cppFunction(
  'std::string shuffleString(std::string s) {
    int x = s.length();
    for (int y = x; y > 0; y--) { 
      int pos = rand()%x;
      char tmp = s[y-1];
      s[y-1] = s[pos];
      s[pos] = tmp;
    }
    return s;
  }'
)
```

For testing, load libraries and write function to generate sequences of length n:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

generate_string <- function(n) {
  paste(sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), n, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
}

sequ <- generate_string(10)

# Test example....

sequ
#> [1] "TTATCAAGGC"

f_question(sequ)
#> [1] "CATGGTACAT"
f_comment(sequ)
#> [1] "GATTATAGCC"
f_biostring(sequ)
#> [[1]]
#>   10-letter "DNAString" instance
#> seq: TAGATCGCAT
shuffleString(sequ)
#> [1] "GATTAATCGC"
stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(sequ)
#> [1] "GAAGTCCTTA"
```

Testing all functions with small n (10 - 100):

```
ns <- seq(10, 100, by = 10)
times <- sapply(ns, function(n) {
  string <- generate_string(n)

  op <- microbenchmark(
    QUESTION     = f_question(string),
    COMMENT      = f_comment(string),
    BIOSTRING    = f_biostring(string),
    RCPP         = shuffleString(string),
    STRINGI      = stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(string)
  )
  by(op$time, op$expr, function(t) mean(t) / 1000)
})
times <- t(times)
times <- as.data.frame(cbind(times, n = ns))

times <- gather(times, -n, key = "fun", value = "time")
pd <- position_dodge(width = 0.2)
ggplot(times, aes(x = n, y = time, group = fun, color = fun)) +
  geom_point(position = pd) +
  geom_line(position = pd) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Biostrings approach is pretty slow.

Dropping this and moving up to 100 - 1000 (code stays same except `ns`):

[image]

The R-based functions (from the question and comment) are comparable, but falling behind.

Dropping these and moving up to 1000 - 10000:

[image]

Looks like the custom Rcpp function is the winner, particularly as the string length grows. However, if choosing between these, consider that the stringi function, [stri_rand_shuffle](https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/blob/cd6eab6e473dd7a7fada2f34e25385632efb1c99/src/stri_random.cpp), will be more robust (e.g., better tested and designed to handle corner cases).

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look at `stri_rand_shuffle()`, from the *stringi* package. It is written entirely in C and should be very efficient. According to the documentation, it

> Generates a (pseudo)random permutation of code points in each string.

Let's try it out:

```
replicate(5, stringi::stri_rand_shuffle("GCTTCG"))
# [1] "GTTCCG" "CCGTTG" "CTCTGG" "CCGGTT" "GTCGCT"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Biostrings](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) package from the Bioconductor repository to do this. Slightly modified from the [PDF  of the Biostrings Documentation](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/manuals/Biostrings/man/Biostrings.pdf):

```
# source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
# biocLite("Biostrings") # installs the package
library(Biostrings)

sequ <- "GCTTCG" # .... in reality much longer

probes <- DNAStringSet(sequ)
probes
probes10 <- head(probes, n=10) #shorter substring
set.seed(33)
shuffled_nucleotides <- lapply(probes10, sample)
shuffled_nucleotides
# optional
DNAStringSet(shuffled_nucleotides)  # does NOT copy the sequence data!
```